# Safari does not load foreign object images for SVG

Tags: image, svg, safari, loading, foreignobject

Safari does not show images for SVG foreign objects from the first time, page refresh is required. Watch the video: https://youtu.be/-rVyWzlhgPw

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #0f0;
      }
    </style>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var data = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="200px"><foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="accent-color: auto; place-content: normal; place-items: normal; place-self: auto; alignment-baseline: auto; animation: 0s ease 0s 1 normal none running none; appearance: none; backdrop-filter: none; backface-visibility: visible; background: none 0% 0% / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgb(255, 0, 0); background-blend-mode: normal; baseline-shift: 0px; block-size: 200px; border-block-end: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-block-start: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 0px; border-style: none; border-width: 0px; border-collapse: separate; border-end-end-radius: 0px; border-end-start-radius: 0px; border-image: none 100% / 1 / 0 stretch; border-inline-end: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-inline-start: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-start-end-radius: 0px; border-start-start-radius: 0px; inset: auto; box-shadow: none; box-sizing: content-box; break-after: auto; break-before: auto; break-inside: auto; buffered-rendering: auto; caption-side: top; caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); clear: none; clip: auto; clip-path: none; clip-rule: nonzero; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color-interpolation: srgb; color-interpolation-filters: linearrgb; color-rendering: auto; columns: auto auto; gap: normal; column-rule: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); column-span: none; content: normal; cursor: auto; cx: 0px; cy: 0px; d: none; direction: ltr; display: block; dominant-baseline: auto; empty-cells: show; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; filter: none; flex: 0 1 auto; flex-flow: row nowrap; float: none; flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); flood-opacity: 1; font: 400 16px &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; font-kerning: auto; font-optical-sizing: auto; grid-auto-columns: auto; grid-auto-flow: row; grid-auto-rows: auto; grid-area: auto / auto / auto / auto; grid-template-areas: none; grid-template-columns: none; grid-template-rows: none; height: 200px; hyphens: manual; image-orientation: from-image; image-rendering: auto; inline-size: 200px; inset-block: auto; inset-inline: auto; isolation: auto; letter-spacing: normal; lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); line-break: auto; list-style: outside none disc; margin-block: 0px; margin: 0px; margin-inline: 0px; marker: none; mask-type: luminance; max-block-size: none; max-height: none; max-inline-size: none; max-width: none; min-block-size: 0px; min-height: 0px; min-inline-size: 0px; min-width: 0px; mix-blend-mode: normal; object-fit: fill; object-position: 50% 50%; offset: none 0px auto 0deg; opacity: 1; order: 0; orphans: 2; outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px; outline-offset: 0px; overflow-anchor: auto; overflow-clip-margin: 0px; overflow-wrap: normal; overflow: visible; overscroll-behavior-block: auto; overscroll-behavior-inline: auto; padding-block: 0px; padding: 0px; padding-inline: 0px; paint-order: normal; perspective: none; perspective-origin: 100px 100px; pointer-events: auto; position: static; r: 0px; resize: none; ruby-position: over; rx: auto; ry: auto; scroll-behavior: auto; scroll-margin-block: 0px; scroll-margin-inline: 0px; scroll-padding-block: auto; scroll-padding-inline: auto; shape-image-threshold: 0; shape-margin: 0px; shape-outside: none; shape-rendering: auto; speak: normal; stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); stop-opacity: 1; stroke: none; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-dashoffset: 0px; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px; tab-size: 8; table-layout: auto; text-align: start; text-align-last: auto; text-anchor: start; text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0); text-decoration-skip-ink: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-overflow: clip; text-rendering: auto; text-shadow: none; text-size-adjust: auto; text-transform: none; text-underline-position: auto; touch-action: auto; transform: none; transform-origin: 100px 100px; transform-style: flat; transition: all 0s ease 0s; unicode-bidi: normal; user-select: auto; vector-effect: none; vertical-align: baseline; visibility: visible; white-space: normal; widows: 2; width: 200px; will-change: auto; word-break: normal; word-spacing: 0px; writing-mode: horizontal-tb; x: 0px; y: 0px; z-index: auto; zoom: 1; -webkit-app-region: none; border-spacing: 0px; -webkit-border-image: none; -webkit-box-align: stretch; -webkit-box-decoration-break: slice; -webkit-box-direction: normal; -webkit-box-flex: 0; -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1; -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; -webkit-box-pack: start; -webkit-font-smoothing: auto; -webkit-highlight: none; -webkit-hyphenate-character: auto; -webkit-line-break: auto; -webkit-locale: &quot;en&quot;; -webkit-mask-box-image-source: none; -webkit-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill; -webkit-mask-box-image-width: auto; -webkit-mask-box-image-outset: 0; -webkit-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch; -webkit-mask: none 0% 0% / auto repeat border-box border-box; -webkit-mask-composite: source-over; -webkit-print-color-adjust: economy; -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18); -webkit-text-combine: none; -webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none; -webkit-text-emphasis: none rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-text-emphasis-position: over right; -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-text-orientation: vertical-right; -webkit-text-security: none; -webkit-text-stroke: 0px rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-user-drag: auto; -webkit-user-modify: read-only; -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;">%0A    <style type="text/css" style="accent-color: auto; place-content: normal; place-items: normal; place-self: auto; alignment-baseline: auto; animation: 0s ease 0s 1 normal none running none; appearance: none; backdrop-filter: none; backface-visibility: visible; background: none 0% 0% / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-blend-mode: normal; baseline-shift: 0px; block-size: auto; border-block-end: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-block-start: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 0px; border-style: none; border-width: 0px; border-collapse: separate; border-end-end-radius: 0px; border-end-start-radius: 0px; border-image: none 100% / 1 / 0 stretch; border-inline-end: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-inline-start: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-start-end-radius: 0px; border-start-start-radius: 0px; inset: auto; box-shadow: none; box-sizing: content-box; break-after: auto; break-before: auto; break-inside: auto; buffered-rendering: auto; caption-side: top; caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); clear: none; clip: auto; clip-path: none; clip-rule: nonzero; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color-interpolation: srgb; color-interpolation-filters: linearrgb; color-rendering: auto; columns: auto auto; gap: normal; column-rule: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); column-span: none; content: normal; cursor: auto; cx: 0px; cy: 0px; d: none; direction: ltr; display: none; dominant-baseline: auto; empty-cells: show; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; filter: none; flex: 0 1 auto; flex-flow: row nowrap; float: none; flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); flood-opacity: 1; font: 400 16px &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; font-kerning: auto; font-optical-sizing: auto; grid-auto-columns: auto; grid-auto-flow: row; grid-auto-rows: auto; grid-area: auto / auto / auto / auto; grid-template-areas: none; grid-template-columns: none; grid-template-rows: none; height: auto; hyphens: manual; image-orientation: from-image; image-rendering: auto; inline-size: auto; inset-block: auto; inset-inline: auto; isolation: auto; letter-spacing: normal; lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); line-break: auto; list-style: outside none disc; margin-block: 0px; margin: 0px; margin-inline: 0px; marker: none; mask-type: luminance; max-block-size: none; max-height: none; max-inline-size: none; max-width: none; min-block-size: 0px; min-height: 0px; min-inline-size: 0px; min-width: 0px; mix-blend-mode: normal; object-fit: fill; object-position: 50% 50%; offset: none 0px auto 0deg; opacity: 1; order: 0; orphans: 2; outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px; outline-offset: 0px; overflow-anchor: auto; overflow-clip-margin: 0px; overflow-wrap: normal; overflow: visible; overscroll-behavior-block: auto; overscroll-behavior-inline: auto; padding-block: 0px; padding: 0px; padding-inline: 0px; paint-order: normal; perspective: none; perspective-origin: 50% 50%; pointer-events: auto; position: static; r: 0px; resize: none; ruby-position: over; rx: auto; ry: auto; scroll-behavior: auto; scroll-margin-block: 0px; scroll-margin-inline: 0px; scroll-padding-block: auto; scroll-padding-inline: auto; shape-image-threshold: 0; shape-margin: 0px; shape-outside: none; shape-rendering: auto; speak: normal; stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); stop-opacity: 1; stroke: none; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-dashoffset: 0px; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px; tab-size: 8; table-layout: auto; text-align: start; text-align-last: auto; text-anchor: start; text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0); text-decoration-skip-ink: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-overflow: clip; text-rendering: auto; text-shadow: none; text-size-adjust: auto; text-transform: none; text-underline-position: auto; touch-action: auto; transform: none; transform-origin: 50% 50%; transform-style: flat; transition: all 0s ease 0s; unicode-bidi: normal; user-select: auto; vector-effect: none; vertical-align: baseline; visibility: visible; white-space: normal; widows: 2; width: auto; will-change: auto; word-break: normal; word-spacing: 0px; writing-mode: horizontal-tb; x: 0px; y: 0px; z-index: auto; zoom: 1; -webkit-app-region: none; border-spacing: 0px; -webkit-border-image: none; -webkit-box-align: stretch; -webkit-box-decoration-break: slice; -webkit-box-direction: normal; -webkit-box-flex: 0; -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1; -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; -webkit-box-pack: start; -webkit-font-smoothing: auto; -webkit-highlight: none; -webkit-hyphenate-character: auto; -webkit-line-break: auto; -webkit-locale: &quot;en&quot;; -webkit-mask-box-image-source: none; -webkit-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill; -webkit-mask-box-image-width: auto; -webkit-mask-box-image-outset: 0; -webkit-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch; -webkit-mask: none 0% 0% / auto repeat border-box border-box; -webkit-mask-composite: source-over; -webkit-print-color-adjust: economy; -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18); -webkit-text-combine: none; -webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none; -webkit-text-emphasis: none rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-text-emphasis-position: over right; -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-text-orientation: vertical-right; -webkit-text-security: none; -webkit-text-stroke: 0px rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-user-drag: auto; -webkit-user-modify: read-only; -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;">%0A      body {%0A        width: 200px;%0A        height: 200px;%0A        margin: 0;%0A        background-color: %23f00;%0A      }%0A    </style>%0A    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" style="accent-color: auto; place-content: normal; place-items: normal; place-self: auto; alignment-baseline: auto; animation: 0s ease 0s 1 normal none running none; appearance: none; backdrop-filter: none; backface-visibility: visible; background: none 0% 0% / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-blend-mode: normal; baseline-shift: 0px; block-size: 100px; border-block-end: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-block-start: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 0px; border-style: none; border-width: 0px; border-collapse: separate; border-end-end-radius: 0px; border-end-start-radius: 0px; border-image: none 100% / 1 / 0 stretch; border-inline-end: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-inline-start: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); border-start-end-radius: 0px; border-start-start-radius: 0px; inset: auto; box-shadow: none; box-sizing: content-box; break-after: auto; break-before: auto; break-inside: auto; buffered-rendering: auto; caption-side: top; caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); clear: none; clip: auto; clip-path: none; clip-rule: nonzero; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color-interpolation: srgb; color-interpolation-filters: linearrgb; color-rendering: auto; columns: auto auto; gap: normal; column-rule: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); column-span: none; content: normal; cursor: auto; cx: 0px; cy: 0px; d: none; direction: ltr; display: inline; dominant-baseline: auto; empty-cells: show; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; filter: none; flex: 0 1 auto; flex-flow: row nowrap; float: none; flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); flood-opacity: 1; font: 400 16px &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; font-kerning: auto; font-optical-sizing: auto; grid-auto-columns: auto; grid-auto-flow: row; grid-auto-rows: auto; grid-area: auto / auto / auto / auto; grid-template-areas: none; grid-template-columns: none; grid-template-rows: none; height: 100px; hyphens: manual; image-orientation: from-image; image-rendering: auto; inline-size: 100px; inset-block: auto; inset-inline: auto; isolation: auto; letter-spacing: normal; lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); line-break: auto; list-style: outside none disc; margin-block: 0px; margin: 0px; margin-inline: 0px; marker: none; mask-type: luminance; max-block-size: none; max-height: none; max-inline-size: none; max-width: none; min-block-size: 0px; min-height: 0px; min-inline-size: 0px; min-width: 0px; mix-blend-mode: normal; object-fit: fill; object-position: 50% 50%; offset: none 0px auto 0deg; opacity: 1; order: 0; orphans: 2; outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px; outline-offset: 0px; overflow-anchor: auto; overflow-clip-margin: 0px; overflow-wrap: normal; overflow: visible; overscroll-behavior-block: auto; overscroll-behavior-inline: auto; padding-block: 0px; padding: 0px; padding-inline: 0px; paint-order: normal; perspective: none; perspective-origin: 50px 50px; pointer-events: auto; position: static; r: 0px; resize: none; ruby-position: over; rx: auto; ry: auto; scroll-behavior: auto; scroll-margin-block: 0px; scroll-margin-inline: 0px; scroll-padding-block: auto; scroll-padding-inline: auto; shape-image-threshold: 0; shape-margin: 0px; shape-outside: none; shape-rendering: auto; speak: normal; stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); stop-opacity: 1; stroke: none; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-dashoffset: 0px; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px; tab-size: 8; table-layout: auto; text-align: start; text-align-last: auto; text-anchor: start; text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0); text-decoration-skip-ink: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-overflow: clip; text-rendering: auto; text-shadow: none; text-size-adjust: auto; text-transform: none; text-underline-position: auto; touch-action: auto; transform: none; transform-origin: 50px 50px; transform-style: flat; transition: all 0s ease 0s; unicode-bidi: normal; user-select: auto; vector-effect: none; vertical-align: baseline; visibility: visible; white-space: normal; widows: 2; width: 100px; will-change: auto; word-break: normal; word-spacing: 0px; writing-mode: horizontal-tb; x: 0px; y: 0px; z-index: auto; zoom: 1; -webkit-app-region: none; border-spacing: 0px; -webkit-border-image: none; -webkit-box-align: stretch; -webkit-box-decoration-break: slice; -webkit-box-direction: normal; -webkit-box-flex: 0; -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1; -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; -webkit-box-pack: start; -webkit-font-smoothing: auto; -webkit-highlight: none; -webkit-hyphenate-character: auto; -webkit-line-break: auto; -webkit-locale: &quot;en&quot;; -webkit-mask-box-image-source: none; -webkit-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill; -webkit-mask-box-image-width: auto; -webkit-mask-box-image-outset: 0; -webkit-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch; -webkit-mask: none 0% 0% / auto repeat border-box border-box; -webkit-mask-composite: source-over; -webkit-print-color-adjust: economy; -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18); -webkit-text-combine: none; -webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none; -webkit-text-emphasis: none rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-text-emphasis-position: over right; -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-text-orientation: vertical-right; -webkit-text-security: none; -webkit-text-stroke: 0px rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-user-drag: auto; -webkit-user-modify: read-only; -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;" />%0A  %0A%0A<style></style></body></foreignObject></svg>';
      var img = new Image(), c = document.getElementById('canvas'), ctx = c.getContext('2d');
      img.onload  = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 200);
      };
      img.src = data;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct. This is tracked here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91523